# Convention on pin shape association for headers on a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design

I want to use such headers below as terminals on PCB to solder power or signal wires to the PCB.

[image]

Is there a convention for square or circle pins association? I mean should square always be the GND or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I am aware, or have seen used, the square pin is only used to indicate Pin #1. Basically a polarity indicator, so you can tell which pin is which from the underside of the board. The latter normally does not have silk-screened details to indicate such information.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hard and fast rule, but generally designers use round pads for most through hole pins and square pads are often used to indicate pin 1.

You can also run a trace closer to the curved edge of the circular pad than you can diagonal to the corner of a square pad if you are running trace clearances close to the process limits.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a formal convention as far as I'm aware, it's up to you. What I have seen and used is that square (1) is the more positive connection. You'll see this often in library parts for polarised caps, diodes etc... Whatever you choose, label it!